# Why Laravel Relation is always empty

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I am trying to establish relation between 2 models but relation to one model is always empty.

I have below models

`Profile Model`

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'members';

    public function photos(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Photo', 'uid', 'id');
    }
}
```

`Photo Model`

```
class Photo extends Model
{
    protected $table = "member_photo";

    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Profile', 'id', 'uid');
    }
}
```

When i try to access relation from photo model to profile model then it is always `empty`.

**belongsTo** is not giving me any relations.

`Member Table`

[image: Member Table]

`Member_photo` table

[image]

Kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

do you have actual related records? Keep in mind you need to have an actual record related. You need to create the tables, using for example

```
php artisan make:migration create_members_table
php artisan make:migration create_members_photo_table
```

then alter the schema in the migration, run it (`php artisan migrate:install / php artisan migrate:refresh`), 
then create the relateds record, you cand easily achieve this using "`php artisan tinker`".

I don't know how you check the relation, but if it returns "empty" it means the relation exists, its just not finding any related record.

Comment: But i do get relations from Profile model to photo model.

Comment: so, you have the tables with records?

Comment: Yeah. U want me to share the records?